# Set base href tag in rails 4 with root_url?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set up a status website for my company, as an webdeveloper using ONLY HTML and Javascript, I'm a bit confused. I've been trying to stay away from rubyonrails for a long time... The doomsday is sadly here.

Where in the app do I set the `<base href="my.domain.com/myapp">`?

I'm using the app [Staytus](https://github.com/adamcooke/staytus). I've read something about `root_url` parameter in `config/routes.rb`. But how do I set it? Any help forward is greatly appreciated. The ruby community doesn't write a lot of syntax to people in forums for some reason..

Comment: What is understand from you question is: **You want to set the root url of you app**. For this you need to define the url in `config/routes.rb`
root 'product#index'
Removed, errors html file from `app/public` i.e 404.html 402.html etc

Answer (score 1):

Found it, in /config/environment/production.rb I added the line: config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myapp"